# How to specify the graphql context (database) in c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphql, graphql-dotnet

So, I'm following this GraphQL tutorial and in it we have the code below and I would like to know how, in NotesMutation, can I use another DB connection in "resolve: context", because I have created another one without Entity Framework:

NotesContext.cs:

```
public class NotesContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }

        public NotesContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }
    }
```

program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<NotesContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISchema, NotesSchema>(services => new NotesSchema(new SelfActivatingServiceProvider(services)));
```

NotesMutation.cs:

```
public class NotesMutation : ObjectGraphType
    {
        public NotesMutation()
        {
            Field<NoteType>(
                "createNote",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(
                    new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>> { Name = "message"}
                ),
                resolve: context =>
                {
                    var message = context.GetArgument<string>("message");
                    var notesContext = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<NotesContext>();
                    var note = new Note
                    {
                        Message = message,
                    };
                    notesContext.Notes.Add(note);
                    notesContext.SaveChanges();
                    return note;
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the context derives from the `<GraphQLType>` and the Type derives from the `ObjectGraphType<Model>`. So, the context will get the context of the model.
I think that may be you want to access some other data from that connection. So, you could define a `<GraphQLType>` of the specific model of that DB Connection and `<NoteType>`, and then you can resolve it in this Field. I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but just gave an opinion.